# Browser Cache memory inflate

Tags: javascript

I am saving some objects (asset bundle or binary files) in the browser cache (index db) the actual size for instance is 461 MB but it showing way too much in the storage tab in Chrome which is more than 7000MB.[image]

I want to ask if is this normal. Here is the code snippet which saving:

```
request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var db = event.target.result;

        // If the object store doesn't exist, it was just created
        if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(sName)) {
            SendMessage('WebglCache', 'OnDataSaveError', 'Error: Object store does not exist.');
            db.close();
            return;
        }

        var transaction = db.transaction([sName], 'readwrite');
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(sName);
         // Sample data to be saved
         var bundleBytes = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, data, dataLength);
        var data = { id: sKey, data: bundleBytes};
        var putRequest = objectStore.put(data);

        putRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
            SendMessage('WebglCache', 'OnDataSaved', 'Data saved to IndexedDB successfully.');
            db.close();
        };

        putRequest.onerror = function (event) {
            SendMessage('WebglCache', 'OnDataSaveError', 'Error saving data to IndexedDB: ' + event.target.error);
            db.close();
        };
    };
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you just `objectStore.put(bundleBytes)`?